# Login Required for Service Account on Google Drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to create/view a Google Doc using a Ruby on Rails app. I think that I am able to create the document but when I click on the link that I get from the API's callback I get an error 401: Login Required.

Here is the code I use the create the document.

```
key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'notasecret')
asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', key)
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization = asserter.authorize()
drive = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')
puts 'hello'
file = drive.files.insert.request_schema.new({
  'title' => 'My document',
  'description' => 'A test document',
  'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
})
puts 'world'
media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(Rails.root.to_s + '/app/assets/documents/document.doc', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => drive.files.insert,
  :body_object => file,
  :media => media,
  :parameters => {
  'uploadType' => 'multipart',
  'alt' => 'json'}
)

puts '==========='
puts result
puts '==========='
jj result.data.to_hash
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: there is a google drive gem, seems to be a lot easier to use from what I can see here.

Comment: Is there a way of getting a link to the google doc using this gem?

Comment: yea, think so, this is it: https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby I'm using for spreadsheets and it's simple.

Comment: Thanks! You're awesome. This gem is really easy to use!

Answer (score 1):

If the link you are clicking is the `downloadUrl` then this will not work in a browser. You should use the `webContentLink` in a browser and be logged into Google.